# 'KeyError:' when iterating over pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nlp

I have a Dataframe df having two columns : 'label' and 'review'. As a data cleaning process, I have dropped all the null values. Now I want to remove all the stopwords and punctuations from review column.

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONm7J.jpg)

I'm getting keyerror when I tried this code.

```
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
    for i in range(len(df)):
        review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ',df['review'][i] )
        review = review.lower()
        review = review.split()
        review = [ stemmer.stem(word) for word in review if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
        df['review'][i] = " ".join(review)
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq9h7.jpg)

```
     KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-44-91ef309cd900> in <module>
          2 
          3 for i in range(len(df)):
     ----> 4     review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ',df['review'][i] )
          5     review = review.lower()
          6     review = review.split()

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
        866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
        867         try:
    --> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
        869 
        870             if not is_scalar(result):

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
       4373         try:
       4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
     -> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
       4376         except KeyError as e1:
       4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

    pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

    pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

    pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

    pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
    pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

    pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
    pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

    KeyError: 140
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Please post the code, not an image of the code. Include the error on the question. The 'KeyError' means that there is no column with the name you attempt to access. Try using `df.columns` to see the exact name of the columns

Answer (score 1):

Below a solution without a loop.
In Pandas use loop as a last resource:

```
df['review'] = df['review'].replace('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',regex=True)
df['review'] = df['review'].str.lower()
df['review'] = df['review'].str.split()
```